# C++ Binary to Decimal

Tags: c++, binary, bitset

So I know there is a way to convert Dec to binary using the bitset library but can you do the same for binary to decimal using the bitset library? or do you have to do it manually?

```
bitset<8> bin_x(number);
```

Comment: In what representation do you have the binary number? Do you need to use `std::bitset` or can you use e. g. a string (in which case, I'd suggest `std::strtol()`)?

Comment: just a normal int. for example int x = 1111; How can i use bitset library to output the decimal number "15" from the binary counterpart "1111"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, but it should be a string.

```
std::bitset<8> bits("1111");
std::cout << bits.to_ulong() << std::endl;
```

You can convert your integer to string and then pass it to `bitset` c-tor.

[Live example](http://ideone.com/aGg2Rx)

Comment: Okay im running into a problem here, I see that you need quotes inside the parentheses for it to work but how can i run this if i have it setup like this? 

std::bitset<8> bits(BinaryNum);

Comment: If `BinaryNum` is char*, or string all will work ok.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way (without using bitset library) using `stoi`

```
// #include <string>
std::string str = "-10010110001";
int dec = std::stoi(bin, nullptr, 2); // dec = -1201
```