# Converting Binary to Decimal built-in function

Tags: c++, binary, type-conversion, decimal

I have to do a binary to decimal conversion in C++.

I know how to do this manually but I was wondering if there exists a function that can do it for me.

For example if I have a decimal number and I wanna print it as a other-base number I just use setbase(base).

```
std::cout<<std::setbase(16)<<20; // prints 20 in base 16.
```

Is there any way to do something like that but to convert from binary to decimal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Binary to Decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627521/c-binary-to-decimal)

Comment: GCC and clang both support binary literals, so you could just do:  `std::cout << std::setbase(16) << 0b101010101;`.

Comment: Binary literals are also part of the upcoming C++14 standard.

Comment: `setbase` only "works" for 8, 10, and 16

Comment: I find `std::bitset` quite handy for this.

Answer (score 6):

```
std::string bin("1101");
int dec = std::stoi(bin, nullptr, 2); // dec = 13
```

Read : [stoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert string to any numbering system like binary, hexadecimal and decimal representation. This is done using the following function:
`stoi(string variable,nullptr,base)`.
The string variable is the variable which needs conversion.
`nullptr` points to an object of type `size_t`, whose value is set by the function to position of the next character in string variable after the numerical value.It may be null pointer. Base may be 2 for binary 16 for hexadecimal 0 for auto base detection.
Note that `stoi` function was introduced in C++11.So make sure your compiler settings are correct and/or your compiler supports C++11.So make sure that your settings are matched with c++11.

Answer (score 0):

//s is binary number as string

```
    bitset<32> b(s);

    int dec=b.to_ulong();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int binaryToDecimal(string s)
{
    bitset<64> bits(s);
    int number = bits.to_ulong();
    return number;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer]. This is especially important when answering old questions (this one is 7 years old) with existing answers. How does this answer improve upon what's already here?